# Wavepackets and the Expansion Postulate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform

The general form of a **wavepacket** satisfying the time-dependent Schrödinger (free particle) equation is:

$$
\psi_{w}(x,t)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i(px-Et)/\hbar}\phi(p)dp.
$$

On the other hand, the **Expansion Postulate** gives us:

$$
\psi_{ep}(x,t) = \sum_{\alpha}c_{\alpha}\psi_{\alpha} e^{-iE_{\alpha}t/\hbar}.
$$

I know the following:

- The wavepacket is a Fourier transform in the $p$-space and the Expansion Postulate is a Fourier series in the $E$-space.
- From the *Expansion Postulate* we can obtain (depending on the Hamiltonian) bound or/and scattering states.

I'm not sure about:

- From the *wavepacket* we can obtain (depending on the Hamiltonian) bound or/and scattering states.

***Question:***

It's correct $\psi_{w}=\psi_{ep}$ ?

Comment: This question might be useful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/293062/coefficients-c-n-in-superposition-of-wave-functions